# How can I divide 333 items in 33 groups where first item will be the biggest and will decrease in an equal amount from the previous one?

Tags: sequences-and-series

There are 333 items. These need to be spread in 33 groups. The first group is the biggest and gets smaller in equal proportion every time. That means
if $n$ is the first one then
$$
n - x \\
n - 2x \\
n - 3x
$$
therefore, 
$$
n + (n-x) + (n-2x) + (n-3x) + \ldots + (n-32x) = 333
$$

I need the value of $n$ and $x$ and let me know how please?

Comment: Have you heard of [Gauss' trick](http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/57919.html)?

Comment: I believe that "gets smaller in equal proportion" means that $g_{n+1}/g_n = g_n/g_{n-1} = ...$. Anyway, even if your definition is correct, you should search for progression sum formulas. It's arithmetic progression if you are right and geometrical if I am.

Comment: @AndreiRykhalski I haven't looked into it, and you might be right, but it seems a bit incredible that there is a positive geometric series of $33$ integers with sum as small as $333$.

Comment: On the left side of the equation: Drop the present parentheses and group differently.

Comment: As said in the solutions below there is no solution in integers. However, if you still want $n$ to be natural you have a solution $$x=\frac{1}{176},n=10.$$

Answer (score 1):

Since
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{33}(a+bk)=33a+561b\tag{1}
$$
we want to solve
$$
33a+561b=333\tag{2}
$$
However, since $33a+561b=33(a+17b)$ and $33\not\mid333$, there can be no integer solutions.

If we are not interested in integer only solutions, there are an infinite number of solutions; for any $a$, we can find a $b$ that solves $(2)$. For example, to get a step of $1$, we use $a=-\frac{76}{11}$ and $b=1$:
$$
\overbrace{\underbrace{\left(-\frac{65}{11}\right)}_{k=1}+\underbrace{\left(-\frac{54}{11}\right)}_{k=2}+\underbrace{\left(-\frac{43}{11}\right)}_{k=3}+\dots+\underbrace{\left(\frac{287}{11}\right)}_{k=33}}^{33\text{ numbers, each differs from the previous by $1$}}=333
$$
However, this does not relate to the problem of dividing a group of objects, which would require an integer sequence.

Comment: I think you need to sum from zero to $32$.

Comment: @OfirSchnabel: That is just a change of the dummy variable. It will not affect the final outcome.

Comment: I agree, just said it in order that your answer will fit the OP notations.

Comment: The problem asks for an arithmetic sequence of $33$ items that sums to $333$. I am simply showing that that is impossible with an integral arithmetic sequence.

Comment: Is it possible to get solution in fractions?

Answer (score 0):

Since $33$ is odd, there would have to be a middle element $m$ in the sequence, which given that is it an arithmetic progression will also be their mean value. But then the sum of the sequence is $33m$, which cannot equal $333$ for any integer value of$~m$.

Comment: Is it possible to get a solution in fractions?

Comment: Of course, take $m=\frac{333}{33}=10+\frac1{11}$, and any fixed decrement $x$ (with $x\leq\frac m{16}=\frac{111}{176}$ if you want t avoid negative numbers).